# How can tooltips be added to a vb.net winforms datagrid row(s)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0, tooltip

I'm looking to add a tooltip to each row in a bound datagrid in vb.net winforms.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but I would give it a shot:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip formToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
formToolTip .SetToolTip(item, "Row Tooltip");
```

Where `item` corresponds to the cell you're setting the tool tip for.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.cells[indexof].ToolTipText= "tootip here".
```

In winforms, it doesn't look like you can do the whole row.

if you NEED the whole row you can loop through the cells.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    cell.ToolTipText = "tooltip here";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If TypeOf control Is TabControl Then
    For Each control1 In control.Controls
        If TypeOf control1 Is TabPage Then
            strControlText = fnGetLanguage(control1.Text)
        End If
        For Each control2 In control1.Controls
            If TypeOf control2 Is label Then
                strControlText = control2.Text
                ' strToolTipText = ToolTip.GetToolTip(control2)
                If strControlText.Contains("*") Then
                    strDizi = Split(strControlText, " ")
                    strControlText = fnGetLanguage(strDizi(0))
                Else
                    strControlText = fnGetLanguage(control2.Text)
                End If
            ElseIf TypeOf control2 Is DataGridView Then
                For i = 0 To control2.ColumnCount - 1
                    strControlText = control2.Columns(i).HeaderText
                    strControlText = fnGetLanguage(strControlText)
                Next
            ElseIf TypeOf control2 Is ComboBox Then
                strControlText = control2.Text
                'strToolTipText = ToolTip.GetToolTip(control2)
                If control2.DataSource Is Nothing Then
                    For i = 0 To control2.Items.Count - 1
                        strControlText = control2.Items(i)
                        strControlText = fnGetLanguage(strControlText)
                    Next
                Else
                    For i = 0 To control2.Items.Count - 1
                        strControlText = control2.Items(i).ToString
                        strControlText = fnGetLanguage(strControlText)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```